# Resizing an iframe

Tags: html, css, video, video-player

I am just wondering, is there anyway to resize a video that is inside an iframe? Below is the code I am working on, when I tried to resize the iframe, it only resizes the wrap and not the player itself therefore creating a scrollbar. Is there anyway to resize the video player itself?

```
<iframe width="600" height="370" src="http://online.fairytail.tv/s/googplayer.php?skintype=nemesis1&amp;to=1002MJumgQZG&amp;autostart=false&amp;id=108994262975881368074/Ft1#5832691710150899906"></iframe>

iframe{
   width: 600px; height: 370px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant style the elements inside iframe from another domain
unless they give you the ability to change some parameters in url or something...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

Here's your [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/q3fLh/)

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $('embed').attr('width', '800');
    $('embed').attr('height', '600');
});
```

Stackoverflow is not a code generator, that's why I only gave you a clue not a simple solution. It would be better if you can work out something and become your own knowledge. Id doesn't mean I don't really know how to.

Comment: Did you read my question above, i said "...is there anyway to resize a video that is INSIDE an IFRAME?...". Where is the iframe in your code? you just gram the embed itself and resize it. I could have easily done that. and you don't really know how to.

Comment: @Bone that's my bad sorry, but you can pass width and height in your iframe src url and change src with javascript or jquery. I'm just try helping that's all. Can't do this in jsfiddle as they use iframe for output already.